# plot 2d level curve from 3d surface data point in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have 3d data that makes a surface when plotted in 3d:

```
x1  y1  f(x1, y1)
x1  y2  f(x1, y2)
..  ..  ..
x1  yn  f(x1, yn)


x2  y1  f(x1, y1)
x2  y2  f(x1, y2)
..  ..  ..
x2  yn  f(x1, yn)


.
.
```

I can use gnuplot to get level curve for x=constant by using :

```
plot "datafile.txt" u 2:3 index 0      //or index 1 etc
```

How can I get plot for y=constant ?

Thanks for reply in advance...

Answer (score 1):

1st possibility: plot the whole file, and make all unwanted datapoints invalid (NaN or 1/0)

```
yfix = 5 # the constant y value
plot datafile using (($2 == yfix) ? $1 : NaN):3
```

2nd possibility: the `every` specifier

```
n = 3 # number of the wanted sample in y-direction
plot datafile every ::n::n using 1:3
```

It takes as option `(line increment):(block increment):(first line):(first block):(last line):(last block)`

So the command above plots only the n'th line from each block, resp. dataset.

(note: blocks are separated by a single blank line, datasets by an additional second blank line. The latter are specified with `index`, the former addressed via `every`)